# How to use aspect ratio constraint in iOS using SnapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I trying to create an aspect ratio constraint 1:1 using snapkit. If I would using storyboard, that could simply be achieved using the aspect ratio constraint tool, but with SnapKit, this not appears to be so easy.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in that way:

```
view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.width.equalTo(view.snp.height).multipliedBy(1.0 / 1.0)
}
```

Using only iOS the following extension works:

```
extension UIView {
    func aspectRatio(_ ratio: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        return NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .width, multiplier: ratio, constant: 0)
    }
}
```